# How to Fix Time String in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, console, datetime-format, timespan

I have a situation where in I have time strings like
10:20:70
11:65:40

I need to convert them into proper time in hh:mm:ss format using c# console.
For eg : 10:20:70 will be 10:21:10 after fixing
26:12:20 will be 02:12:10 as 26hours to be considered as 2 hours

How to achieve this? Please help me out.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is this *always* going to be three two-digits number separated by colon, or is there other format? Do you want the return as string, or a proper DateTime/TimeSpan?

Comment: @Martheen, format will be same always

Comment: Then just split them https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split parse https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse and distribute the overflow to the next element

Comment: Timespan won't work for out of range elements

Comment: When I say the *return*, I mean after fixing the overflow if you want them as proper TimeSpan or just a string for display

Comment: The link I gave you talk about treating them as regular number, not TimeSpan or DateTime

Comment: `new TimeSpan(split[0]%24,split[1]%60,split[2]%60);` wont that be enought ? You are just looking modulo operator right `%` ?

Answer (score 0):

Split the input and and either use a TimeSpan to get the real representation of the input.
Or use modulo operator `%` to fix the overflow.

```
var split = date.Split(":").Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
if(split.Count() != 3) {Console.WriteLine("bad format"); continue;}

/// public TimeSpan (int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
var realTimeSpanRepresentation = new TimeSpan(split[0],split[1],split[2]);          
var correctedTimeSpanRepresentation = new TimeSpan(split[0]%24,split[1]%60,split[2]%60);            

Console.WriteLine(date+" => "+realTimeSpanRepresentation+" / "+correctedTimeSpanRepresentation);        


/// public DateTime (int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second);
//var realDateTimeRepresentation = new DateTime(1,1,1,split[0],split[1],split[2]);  // Will go boom cause overflow      
var correctedDateTimeRepresentation = new DateTime(1,1,1,split[0]%24,split[1]%60,split[2]%60);

Console.WriteLine(date+" => "+correctedDateTimeRepresentation);
```

Result:

```
10:20:70 => 10:21:10 / 10:20:10
10:20:70 => 01/01/0001 10:20:10

11:65:40 => 12:05:40 / 11:05:40
11:65:40 => 01/01/0001 11:05:40

99:99:99 => 4.04:40:39 / 03:39:39
99:99:99 => 01/01/0001 03:39:39
```

demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uwb4zc

NB: I nammed it real representation, cause Imo "00:60:00" is one Hour not "00:00:00"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that takes a total amount of seconds and gives proper values for how many years, days, hours, minutes and seconds in there.

```
public static void GetTimeFromSeconds(float secondsTotal, out int s, out int m, out int h, out int d, out int y)
{
    s = m = h = d = y = 0;

    s = (int)(secondsTotal % 60);
    // substruct the seconds remainder from the total amount (75 - 15 = 60, 125 - 5 = 120).
    secondsTotal -= s;
    // if nothing left then it was less than 1 minute (45 - 0 = 45).
    if (secondsTotal < 60)
        return;

    // secondsTotal / 60 => how many minutes total
    // % 60 => how many minutes remain after splitting to whole hours
    m = (int)(secondsTotal / 60 % 60);
    // substruct the minutes remainder from the total amount (every minute takes 60 secs from the total)
    secondsTotal -= m * 60;
    // if there's not enough seconds remain in the total to get at least 1 whole hour (3600 secs)
    // then it means there was less than 1 hour.
    if (secondsTotal < 3600)
        return;

    // secondsTotal / 3600 => how many hours total
    // % 24 => what will remain after splitting to whole days (24 hours)
    h = (int)(secondsTotal / 3600 % 24);
    // every whole hour takes 3600 secs from the total
    secondsTotal -= h * 3600;
    // 24 hours = 86400 seconds.
    // If there's less remaining than it was less than 24 hours.
    if (secondsTotal < 86400)
        return;

    // secondsTotal/ 86400 => how many days total
    // % 365 => how many will remain after splitting to years
    d = (int)(secondsTotal / 86400 % 365);
    // substruct whole days
    secondsTotal -= d * 86400;
    // 1 year = 31536000 secs.
    // is there enough secs remaining to get a whole year?
    if (secondsTotal < 31536000)
        return;

    y = (int)(secondsTotal / 31536000);
}
```

So, you could parse your time into separate values

`26:70:20 => hours=26, minutes=70, seconds=20`
then count the total amount of seconds:
`secondsTotal = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds`
and then use the method above:

```
int years, days, hours, mins, secs;
GetTimeFromSeconds(secondsTotal, out secs, out mins, out hours, out days, out years);
```

For 26 hours, 70 mins, 20 secs the results will be `days: 1, hours: 3, minutes: 10, secs: 20`.
Then format it into the format you need. For example:

```
TimeSpan properTime = new TimeSpan(hours, mins, secs);
properTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```